# adding an object to an arraylist, Bank account

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having a problem adding an object to an arraylist,and I cant seem to find the problem. It deletes previous object when I`m adding new account. Please, help!

```
public class bankmain {
    static File f=new File("C:/Users/Guest/workspace/bank.txt");
    private static ArrayList<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Account selectedAccount;
    private static Account selectedAccount2;
    private static boolean flag = false;
    private static boolean fly=true;
    private static double amount;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //readFile();    
        System.out.println("Enter the option for the operation you need:");
        System.out.println("1-List of accounts");
        System.out.println("2-Create new account");
        System.out.println("3-Delete account");
        System.out.println("4-Exit");
        System.out.println("5-Deposit");
        System.out.println("6-Withdraw");
        System.out.println("7-Transfer");
        while (fly) {
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                // List
                for (int i = 0; i < accountList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Owner:"+accountList.get(i).getOwner()+"-Account Number:"+accountList.get(i).getAccNumber()+"-Balance:"+accountList.get(i).getBalance());
                }
                break;
                case 2:
                // Create
                int accNo;
                Double bal;
                String own;
                System.out.println("Enter owners name: ");
                own=scan.next();
                System.out.println("Enter account number: ");
                accNo = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter initial balance: ");
                bal = scan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Owner:" + own+ " Balance:" + bal + " Account Number:"+accNo );
                Account k=new Account(bal, accNo, own);
                accountList.add(k);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enter the option for the operation you need:

```
 1. List of accounts
 2. Create new account
 3. Delete account
 4. Exit
 5. Deposit
 6. Withdraw
 7. Transfer


Enter owners name: 

Anna

Enter account number: 

1

Enter initial balance: 

1200

Owner:Anna Balance:1200.0 Account Number:1

2

Enter owners name: 

Lana

Enter account number: 

2

Enter initial balance: 

3000

Owner:Lana Balance:3000.0 Account Number:2

1

Owner:Lana-Account Number:2-Balance:3000.0

Owner:Lana-Account Number:2-Balance:3000.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no issue with your code. I have run the code and I could see accounts added correctly.
Here is `Account class` definition :

```
class Account {

    private double balance;
    private int accNumber;
    private String owner;

    public Account(Double bal, int accNo, String own) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.balance = bal;
        this.accNumber = accNo;
        this.owner = own;
    }

    public int getAccNumber() {
        return accNumber;
    }

    public void setAccNumber(int accNumber) {
        this.accNumber = accNumber;
    }

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

}
```

Here is the result :

Enter the option for the operation you need:

1-List of accounts

2-Create new account

3-Delete account

4-Exit

5-Deposit

6-Withdraw

7-Transfer

2

Enter owners name:

Alan

Enter account number:

1

Enter initial balance:

10000

Owner:Alan Balance:10000.0 Account Number:1

2

Enter owners name:

Balan

Enter account number:

2

Enter initial balance:

20000

Owner:Balan Balance:20000.0 Account Number:2

2

Enter owners name:

colon

Enter account number:

3

Enter initial balance:

3000

Owner:colon Balance:3000.0 Account Number:3

1

Owner:Alan-Account Number:1-Balance:10000.0

Owner:Balan-Account Number:2-Balance:20000.0

Owner:colon-Account Number:3-Balance:3000.0

Answer (score 3):

You should look into your `Account` class. You probably declared the properties to be static, which means all `Account` instances would have the same properties. Remove the static keyword.